# reading an excel in java, variables are empty

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, return, xlsx

I try to read this excel file: Test.xlsx, to do this I used an example I found on the internet, but

I used this link as en example: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

it doens't work.
I copied the url for the file, so there is no error there.
Whenever I run it, it doensnt show errors just : []
When I debug it, it shows me that the listsize = 0

What should I change?

```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


   @Override

   public List<String> getExcel(){

    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Test.xlsx"));


        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file 
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook 
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

        //Iterate through each rows one by one 
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();


        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns 

            if (row.getRowNum() <= 7) {
            continue;// skip to read the first 7 row of file
            }


            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                list.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
            //System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;


}
```

Comment: It would help to show some example XML :)

Comment: which one u need ? got the web and project XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong class for the file you are trying to open (Test.xlsx). By the extension, I can assume this is an Excel 2007 or later document. Use `HSSFWorkbook` for Excel 2003 and `XSSFWorkbook` for Excel 2007 or later. Review Apache POI documentation that came with the downloaded package. It contains basic tutorials on how to accomplish this.

You will need to replace all of the 'HSSF' classes for the 'XSSF' equivalent.  Beware that the methods called to create the parts of the document (i.e. Workbook, Sheet, etc) are not always the same.

Try this [link](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0ByKX_sfg7kyeOE9hOUp1T016NW8). I created a small demo for a simple tutorial on Apache POI some time back.  There is an Excel example you could follow.  The location contains source code and a set of slides that you should be able to follow easily.

Comment: @Mr.Mathy I just updated the answer with a link to a tutorial I wrote a couple of years ago. There a some slides and some source code I put on Google drive and should be accessible to anyone with the link. If you can't access, let me know.  There should be a Word tutorial and an Excel tutorial there.

Comment: The stuff is there if you need it.  Good luck! :)

Comment: I changed the hssf to xssf, but now i get another error and I'm stuck again :p so I posted the other error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731531/resource-injection-error-on-managed-bean-when-reading-excel-in-java